# Google app engine site verification fails

Tags: google-app-engine

Google app engine site verification fails, but `dig`shows that the txt record is there

```
> +short TXT google-site-verification.[insert-site-name].org
    "[insert-correct-verification-string]"
```

Google has no support for the free level. Is there anything that I can do?

My zone file:

```
$ORIGIN danielzfranklin.org.
$TTL 1800
danielzfranklin.org. IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.danielzfranklin.org. 1434159020 10800 3600 604800 1800
danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN NS ns1.digitalocean.com.
danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN NS ns2.digitalocean.com.
danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN NS ns3.digitalocean.com.
danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN A 162.243.157.149
ace.danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN A 104.236.132.126
yamail-5e8e38f3f733.danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN CNAME mail.yandex.com.
danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN MX 10 mx.yandex.ru.
google-site-verification.danielzfranklin.org. 1800 IN TXT 5AikMLQ3ioZyTASSIWK-fI3Elz3Ba9AhijhCmU1MIjY
```

My DNS settings look like this:
[image]

The domain name was bought from namecheap and is not a Google apps domain.

Comment: put the code in the HTML instead?

Comment: @user2266449 That does not appear as an option when verifying for Google App Engine

Comment: You will probably need to show how you've set your other records, and whether this is a Google apps domain, or an alias for a Google apps domain. It all works when it's exactly right, but doesn't at all otherwise.

Comment: @Nick I added what you asked for

Answer (score -1):

Try CNAME record instead. It worked for me.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed summary of what you did here?